# Handling autopostback in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I handle autopoatback in ASP.NET MVC? Suppose I have a textbox. I enter a value in it, I need to check if the value exists in some table in the database. So in ASP.NET forms I can set `AutoPostBack = true` and handle the `TextBox.TextChanged` event. How do I do it here?

And what are the pros and cons of using ASP.NET server control in MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no postbacks in ASP.NET MVC. What you need to do here is an AJAX call to a Controller action on the server.

Here's an example http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCPreview4UsingAjaxAndAjaxForm.aspx

Comment: "There are no postbacks in ASP.NET MVC" -- that's not true.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is - don't use ASP.NET server controls in ASP.NET MVC. ViewState is not supported in MVC and using 'codebehind' files completely against the methodology of MVC - you don't 'handle events' you submit values to a controller which then handles the logic and returns a view.

As you don't seem clear on what MVC is, I would suggest that before embarking on an MVC project you first read [Comparing Web Forms And ASP.NET MVC by Dino Esposito](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942833.aspx) (MSDN). This should give you an overview on the differences between web forms and MVC. If you then wish to use MVC I would strongly suggest you visit http://www.asp.net/mvc/ and watch and read the tutorials to get a flavour for it. It's not something you can just dive into as it is a very different framework to standard web forms and requires a whole new mindset. Once you've done that, get a good book, such as Steve Sanderson's [Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pro-ASP-NET-MVC-V2-Framework/dp/1430228865/) (V2 is released in May, so wait for that).

Comment: ok..thanks.. I am new to MVc..just getting started.i ll do that

Comment: MVC requires you to learn a lot of new concepts and methodologies, but (IMO) it's worth it. Good luck!